# How transform an irregular table with false days for a regular time series?

Tags: r, datatable, time-series

I have a lot of tables with climate observations in daily frequency. As you can see all columns of months have 31 days. I wanna organize this data correctly, excluding all false days and transform in a regular time series.

data view:
[image]

dput(head(data,31)):

```
structure(list(NA. = 1:31, JAN = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), FEV = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), MAR = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12.5, 0), ABR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, NA), MAI = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.8, 0, 0, 0), JUN = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 6.8, 2.4, 2.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), JUL = c(0, 0, 4.4, 0, 0, 
15.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.2, 0, 1.3, 0, 0, 1.7, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AGO = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.1, 4, 2.6, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), SET = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), OUT = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), NOV = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA), DEZ = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
31L), class = "data.frame")
```

I wanna like this example:

[image]

original data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xizr6fhbriieds/data.csv?dl=0

Please, anyone help-me. Is for my scientific initiation.

Comment: is it starting from the year 2000?

Comment: I tried put data as you required. But i don`t know how work dput().

Comment: Not exactly. This year i put for example. My data set there so many different years. But, if i can work with this set in example, I will actually be able to do with the others.

Comment: Done! I think that is correctly now.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not totally clear from your question how you want to filter the data, but to convert to long form and remove `NA`s, one approach would be with `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `lubridate`.

I'm using `data.table` to load your data because for some reason it's semicolon separated even though the file extension is `.csv`.

You could probably get away with not renaming the months since your local probably accepts Spanish month abbreviations.

```
libary(data.table)
data <- fread("data.csv")
names(data) <- c("Day",month.abb)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
Year <- 2000
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Day,names_to = "Month") %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(paste(Day,Month,Year))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  select(Date,value)
#   Date       value
#   <date>     <dbl>
# 1 2000-07-03   4.4
# 2 2000-08-05   1.9
# 3 2000-06-06   3.4
# 4 2000-07-06  15.4
# 5 2000-04-12   1.9
# 6 2000-06-15   7  
# 7 2000-07-16   2.2
# 8 2000-07-18   1.3
# 9 2000-05-21   2.5
#10 2000-07-21   1.7
```

Comment: Hey, brother. Do you help-me again? How i can make the year variate? In this code, the year is constant. May i have a time series with year start in 2000 and varying for next year? eg: 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003...

Comment: How do you know what year the data is from? The starting data in your question doesn't have the year anywhere actually in it. I just chose 2000 because that's what your desired output had.